# How should I accomplish my rating script

Tags: php, javascript, html, rating-system

My webpage has a table where you can select different items. I want to be able to let people rate these. I ran into a problem where I would need to pass a javascript variable to php, and from what I read online isn't the easiest thing. How would you suggest I do this?

The code is stored at 98.214.131.200/index.php and 98.214.131.200/ratings/ratings.php

currently I have functions in ratings.php that allow me to write or read the ratings, but I need the a string from the javascript to identify which item is being rated.

Comment: Are you populating the table based on a database (SQL I'm guessing)?

Comment: Nope, it's just written in javascript. If you open index.php, you can see the entire table.

Comment: Javascript is client-side.  How are you storing the ratings?  With Javascript, it's stored on the clients browser but once they reload it it is gone.

Comment: It's stored on my server, once you run the php function submitRating($id, $rating) it updates a file and you can read the value back with getRating($id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the rating using a POST request from a form.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php/

Make sure you correctly sanitize your inputs to avoid SQL injections

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery, and pass the information behind the scenes.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/your/processing/url/here.php",
  data: {rating_id: item_id, rating: 4},  // <-- set this dynamically with your item
  success: function()
  {
    // do something - success
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Yes, this would be the best way to do it. I was under the impression that the OP didn't have much experience with jQuery or even Javascript. So, adding onto this, you would need to download the jQuery library and include link it to your pages that use it.

Comment: This is the first website I've ever coded so I'm not very experienced with anything, would this way allow multiple submissions though? I don't plan on sending the user to a new page.

Comment: Yes, the submissions would be done without leaving the page, and you could tie them to a button click event. If this is your first time working with web development you might have some difficulties getting everything to work, so check out the documentation at jQuery.com thoroughly if you plan to do it this way. Other than that, I think the quick fix would be to just add a line in your ratings.php file like "redirect('./index.php');", and that will bring the user back to the voting page. Since it's a PHP redirect, it will happen without the user noticing. It's not like a javascript redirect.

Comment: I embeded google maps onto the page, and content is added to it by the user. Would the content not be removed when redirected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the rating as a `GET` variable in the URL directly. That way you can do ./ratings.php?rating=5&item=20, and get those values in PHP as `$_GET['rating']` and `$_GET['item']`.

Comment: The problem with that is I already have loaded the php file, and if were to just make another php where the variable can be passed that way it would only allow me to rate once.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could redirect the user back to index.php faster than he would realize he even left the page in the first place.

Comment: but then the content the user has added to the map on index.php would be reset, which is not favorable.

Comment: I understand. Then yes, you are probably getting into the realm of jQuery/ajax requests in order to get this done.